# Grow and shrink selection keybindings in IntelliJ Cursive

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure, selection, paredit, cursive

Which keybindings should I configure in IntelliJ Cursive to get the "expand" and "shrink" selection behaviour documented in the [ParEdit user guide](https://cursiveclojure.com/userguide/paredit.html)?

The user guide mentions <kbd>Alt+Up</kbd> and <kbd>Alt+Down</kbd>, but as someone new to structural editing, I'm struggling to find the right keybinding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends which platform you're on. Generally you don't have to configure these actions since they're built in to IntelliJ, they're not Cursive specific. Alt-Up and Alt-Down are for the Mac OSX 10.5+ keymap, recommended if you're on a Mac. In the Default keymap, which is what you'll get if you're on Windows or Linux it's Ctrl-W and Shift-Ctrl-W.

These actions are called "Extend/Shrink Selection" on v14, and on earlier versions (probably for historical reasons) they're "Select/Unselect Word at Caret". They can be found by searching in the Keymaps panel.

Comment: What are these keybindings called?

Comment: It depends which version of IntelliJ you're using. On v14 they're called "Extend/Shrink Selection". On earlier versions (probably for historical reasons) they're "Select/Unselect Word at Caret".

Comment: `Select Word at Caret` is the answer I was looking for, thanks :). If you update your answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to change any keybindings, make sure you do them in the top-level `Prefs -> Keymap` settings, NOT in the `Prefs -> Keymap -> Clojure Keybindings` window. Those are not meant to be edited. On a Mac for example, the default cursive keybinding for `Wrap []` clobbered the basic backward navigation keybinding.

This [issue](https://github.com/cursiveclojure/cursive/issues/552) cleared up the confusion for me.